# Assign Data To Value Dynamically In Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I'm running the `for loop` inside row and want to assign data to `value` field from **filterData**. I don't want to assign data to value dynamically.

```
<ion-row *ngFor="let type of filterData">
    <ion-segment [(ngModel)]="selectedSegment" (ionChange)="onSegmentChanged($event)">
       <ion-segment-button value="Must be came from *ngFor">
        {{type.key}}
       </ion-segment-button>
    </ion-segment>
    </ion-row>
```

filterData array holds:

```
this.filterData=[
  {"key":"Budget","value":"a1","type":"bar","labelid":"17"},
  {"key":"Parking Capacity","value":"a2","type":"checkbox","labelid":"12"},
  {"key":"Venue","value":"a3","type":"checkbox","labelid":"3"},
  {"key":"No.of Rooms","value":"a4","type":"checkbox","labelid":"15"},
  {"key":"Max.Capacity","value":"a5","type":"bar","labelid":"1"},
  {"key":"Function Type","value":"a6","type":"checkbox","labelid":"11"}];
```

I want to assigne value data that is in `json`'s value field of elements and not able to do that .

Is there any way to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind value to `ion-segment-button` by `"value={{type.value}}"` or `[value]="type.value"`.

```
<ion-segment-button [value]="type.value">
  {{type.key}}
</ion-segment-button>

<ion-segment-button value="{{type.value}}">
  {{type.key}}
</ion-segment-button>
```

see **[working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-vqh9kz?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html)**.

Comment: <ion-item *ngFor="let function of filterData">
                <div [class.hide]="function.type">{{function.labelid}}</div>
              </ion-item>  Is it possible to change the status of type from typescript .

Comment: @SurajBahadur yeah, just change  `selectedSegment` to another `ion-segment-button`'s value. see updated demo.

Comment: it working awesome in ion-segment-button 's value.  <ion-item *ngFor="let function of filterData"> <div [class.hide]="function.type">{{function.labelid}}</div> </ion-item> Here in this code i was trying to hide and show div based on "function.type" value and want to set it value through typescript but it doesn't work . i really appreciate your effort . please look into this . Thank you

Comment: @SurajBahadur just change `[class.hide]` to `[hidden]` should solve your problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154338/discussion-between-suraj-bahadur-and-pengyy).